# EF Core relations - redundant column id

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

```
public class Post
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public List<File> Files { get; set; }
}

public class File
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string PhysicalPath { get; set}
}
```

And I'm not sure why EF Core creates File Table as:

> Id, PhysicalPath, PostId

Why he cannot map ID's of every element of `List<Files>` of Post to File.ID instead of creating additional column?

Is there any other solution that changing

`public List<File> Files { get; set; }`

to

`public List<Guid> Files { get; set; }`

and sending another query to load all of those Files?

e.g

```
var from_db = new List<File>();

foreach (var fileID in Post.Files)
{
    from_db.Add(_context.files.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == FileId));
}
```

Of course I'm not saying that this "way" to load list is "the most efficent" cuz for sure it's possible to load all them in one query, but this is not the thing to think about in this thread.

Comment: It's not redundant. This is how relational databases store/retrieve related records. Imagine you what to get `File` records **from the database table**  for specific `Post`. How would you do that w/o  `PostId` column in the table?

Comment: @IvanStoev So, for every relation with other_type_object there's gonna be column with an ID?

Comment: I think [Relationships](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships) documentation topic will explain it better than me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could specify the relationship more explicitly by adding a virtual `Post` and a PostId property to the `File` class:

```
public class Post
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual List<File> Files { get; set; }
}

public class File
{
    public virtual Post Post { get; set; }
    public Guid PostId { get set; }

    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string PhysicalPath { get; set}
}
```

You could then use the Nuget package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies, and load them for example as:

```
var post = _context.Posts.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == yourid);
```

The `File`s of the post will load when accessing them.

Comment: How's that different from using ``Include``?

Comment: Include uses eager loading (loading as part of the original query), while lazy loading loads the navigation properties when accessed. Read more at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data